# Could I apply Rice theorem for both TM's property and language property?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, rice-theorem

I read that Rice theorem applicable only for language property not for machine property. But today I  have read from [stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117125/can-i-apply-rices-theorem-to-decide-decidability-status-of-these-languages) and one site they are applying Rice theorem on machine also. My question is could we for both or language only?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Could you link to the "stack exchange and one site"? Also, don't forget that answers in [so] and other sites on theory of computation tend to be wrong, since they are given by people who are not experts.

Comment: @Yuval [See this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117125/can-i-apply-rices-theorem-to-decide-decidability-status-of-these-languages)

Comment: Rice's theorem is just one way of showing that a language is not decidable. There could be other ways.

Comment: Rice's theorem states that if $P$ is any property of languages satisfies some nontriviality property, then the language of Turing machines computing a language is $P$ is undecidable. If your language is of this form, then you can apply Rice's theorem to conclude that it is undecidable. If it isn't, then you cannot.

Comment: @Yuval I have shared the link, the answer is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by formulating Rice's theorem.

> Fix an alphabet $\Sigma$. We consider Turing machines that recognize languages over $\Sigma$ (the language recognized by a Turing machine consists of all inputs on which the Turing machine halts).
>
> A collection $p$ of languages over $\Sigma$ is *nontrivial* if
>
> 1. $L(M_1) \in p$ for some Turing machine $M_1$.
> 2. $L(M_2) \notin p$ for some Turing machine $M_2$.
>
> **Theorem.** If $p$ is non-trivial then $\{ M : L(M) \in p \}$ is undecidable.

The question you link to mentions two different languages. The first language $L_1$ is described extremely vaguely. One possible interpretation, inspired by the OP's vague comments, is that $L_1$ consists of all Turing machines $M$ for which there exists an input $x$ such that when running $M$ on $x$, the symbol $\sigma$ gets printed on the tape.

The second language $L_2$ is described more concretely, even though some vagueness still remains. It consists of all Turing machines $M$ such that for all integers $x,y$, if we run $M$ on input $\langle x,y \rangle$ then $M$ halts and outputs $\langle xy \rangle$; here $\langle xy \rangle$ is the encoding of the integer $xy$ according to some fixed encoding scheme, and $\langle x,y \rangle$ is similarly the encoding of the pair of integers $x,y$.

As you can see, none of the two languages are of the form considered by Rice's theorem. One of the answers mentions an extension of Rice's theorem which captures $L_2$, but doesn't provide any more details.

We can show that $L_1$ is undecidable by reduction from the halting problem. Given a Turing machine $M$, construct a Turing machine $M'$ which erases its input, simulates $M$, and prints $\sigma$ once $M$ halts (we arrange that $M$ never uses the symbol $\sigma$). Then $M$ halts iff $M' \in L_1$.

We can also show that $L_2$ is undecidable by reduction from the halting problem. Given a Turing machine $M$, construct a Turing machine $M'$ which runs $M$ on a parallel empty tape, and once it halts, checks whether the input to $M'$ is of the form $\langle x,y \rangle$, and if so, computes $\langle xy \rangle$ (otherwise we don't care what $M'$ does; it can just immediately halt). Then $M$ halts iff $M' \in L_2$.